# Discord & Google Sheets webhook not working properly with formulas

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm unable to use this javascript code to look for changes in certain coulms if the cell is updated by a formula. If it is manually updated, it works fine.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  if (event && event.range) {
    var sheetName = "Sheet2";
    var columnsToWatch = [5, 6, 7];
    var range = event.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();

    if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && columnsToWatch.indexOf(column) !== -1) {
      var value = range.getValue();
      var timestamp = new Date();
      var data = {
        "content": "A change was made to " + sheetName + ", row " + row + ", column " + column + ":\n\n" +
          "Value: " + value + "\n" +
          "Timestamp: " + timestamp
      };
      var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
      };
      var url = "[Webhook]";
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    }`
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the function but I'm unable to find a function which would fit the script. pretty new at this stuff so im honestly just confused

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I'm unable to use this javascript code to look for changes in certain coulms if the cell is updated by a formula. If it is manually updated, it works fine.` and your showing the script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my lack of explanation. I am trying to write a code which would send a message into a discord server via a webhook every time there is a change in a cell in the specified columns. In this case the columns should be column 5,6 and 7. If there are any changes in the cells a discord message would be sent. This works completely fine if I manually change the values of the cell, however it does not work at all if there is a formula changing the values of the cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.